# fstab mount is delayed

Tags: networking, systemd, fstab

I just installed the newest version of Manjaro ARM on an sd-card for my Raspberry Pi 4. Now I am trying to mount two directories located on my Synology NAS permantly (via network of course) using the fstab. On all my other system (including older Manjaro-versions), this works with the very same two lines in my fstab (here just one for example):
`//192.168.1.61/inventory        /mnt/DS_216/inventory   cifs users,vers=3.0,credentials=/mnt/DS_216/216credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,workgroup=WORKGROUP,noauto,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=0,_netdev   0       0`
However, this time, it didn't seem to work at the beginning, until I found out that it actually did work, but with one major problem: It delays pretty exactly 1 minute and 40 seconds before it actually mounts, although everything else is already loaded. When I open a terminal just after boot, I see just a black screen, and it takes the said amount of time until the `username@hostname$` line appears. If I press Ctrl+C in this timespan, it appears instantly.

Looking at the journalctl output, you can kind of see what is happening, although it doesn't make a lot of sense: It says, that the network couldn't be configured, but if I ping anything just after boot, it works fine. Also, all of the stuff that is happening here according to journalctl, shouldn't all of this be AFTER fstab has been executed fully? As I said, this never happened on older manjaro versions. What am I missing out on here? Did I misunderstand the journalctl output? Or is there some delay hardcoded into systemd that I don't know about?

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me.

Here is the relevant part of the journalctl output:

````
Jun 03 19:49:54 Raspi4 systemd[1]: mnt-DS_216-FamilyTransfer.automount: Got automount request for /mnt/DS_216/FamilyTransfer, triggered by 880 (silver)
Jun 03 19:49:55 Raspi4 guake.desktop[733]: Guake initialized
Jun 03 19:49:57 Raspi4 org.moson.matray.desktop[682]: matray started.
Jun 03 19:49:57 Raspi4 matray[682]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jun 03 19:49:59 Raspi4 kernel: cam-dummy-reg: disabling
Jun 03 19:50:16 Raspi4 systemd[413]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
Jun 03 19:50:16 Raspi4 gsd-media-keys[909]: Sending 'toggle' message to Guake3
Jun 03 19:50:16 Raspi4 gnome-shell[478]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x60000c
Jun 03 19:50:16 Raspi4 gnome-shell[478]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x60000c
Jun 03 19:50:18 Raspi4 gnome-shell[478]: updates_checker.vala:71: check updates
Jun 03 19:50:18 Raspi4 kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:1028.0006: HID++ 1.0 device connected.
Jun 03 19:50:18 Raspi4 upowerd[562]: treated changed event as add on /sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2/1-1.3.2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:1028.0006/power_supply/hid>
Jun 03 19:50:19 Raspi4 guake.desktop[733]: Spawning new terminal at /home/benedikt
Jun 03 19:50:19 Raspi4 systemd[413]: Started VTE child process 950 launched by guake process 733.
Jun 03 19:50:20 Raspi4 gnome-shell[478]: updates_checker.vala:101: 0 updates found
Jun 03 19:50:20 Raspi4 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 03 19:50:21 Raspi4 systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 03 19:50:46 Raspi4 geoclue[579]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
Jun 03 19:50:46 Raspi4 systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 03 19:50:48 Raspi4 dbus-daemon[430]: [session uid=1000 pid=430] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=1000 pid=478 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell")
Jun 03 19:50:48 Raspi4 systemd[413]: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Jun 03 19:50:48 Raspi4 dbus-daemon[430]: [session uid=1000 pid=430] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Jun 03 19:50:48 Raspi4 systemd[413]: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Jun 03 19:51:34 Raspi4 systemd-networkd-wait-online[289]: Timeout occurred while waiting for network connectivity.
Jun 03 19:51:34 Raspi4 systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 03 19:51:34 Raspi4 systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 03 19:51:34 Raspi4 systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured.
Jun 03 19:51:34 Raspi4 systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Jun 03 19:51:34 Raspi4 systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/DS_216/FamilyTransfer...
Jun 03 19:51:34 Raspi4 systemd[1]: Starting Samba NMB Daemon...
Jun 03 19:51:34 Raspi4 kernel: FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
Jun 03 19:51:34 Raspi4 kernel: Key type cifs.spnego registered
Jun 03 19:51:34 Raspi4 kernel: Key type cifs.idmap registered
Jun 03 19:51:34 Raspi4 kernel: CIFS: Attempting to mount \\192.168.1.61\FamilyTransfer
Jun 03 19:51:34 Raspi4 systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/DS_216/FamilyTransfer.```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, NetworkManager and systemd-networkd were both running, so that they were blocking each other somehow, and therefore a two minute timeout of systemd-networkd had to end before the fstab was executed. This also explains why a network connection was there all the time. Turning off the networkd service and sticking with NetworkManager (`systemctl disable systemd-networkd-wait-online`) fixed all my problems.